# Proving that n = O (log(n)) is not true.

Tags: limits

Definition that we're using the question:

Let f,g : N→ (0,∞). We write "f(n) is O(g(n))" to mean there is M>0 and $n_0$ ∈ N such that for all n ⩾ $n_0$ we have f(n) ⩽ Mg(n).

My question is the following:

Is n = O(log(n)) true?

I want to say no but I don't know how to prove that for any M > 0 there is no $n_0$ ∈ N such that for all n ⩾ $n_0$ we have n ⩽ Mlog(n).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove it because it is not correct and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\over\log n}=\infty$$. Actually $$\log n=O(n)$$because $$\log n<n$$for $n\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

From
$$ e^t\ge 1+t\qquad\text{for all }t\in\Bbb R,$$
we get for $t>0$
$$ \frac{e^t}t=\frac{(e^{t/2})^2}t\ge\frac{(1+\frac t2)e^{t/2}}t>\frac12e^{t/2}.$$
Substituting $t\leftarrow \ln n$, this becomes
$$ \frac n{\ln n}>\frac12\sqrt n$$
and the right hand side is clearly unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

One route is to show that $\frac{n}{\log n}$ tends to infinity as $n \to \infty$. (If the ratio were bounded for all large $n$, then you could choose $M$ to be that bound; on the other hand if the ratio tends to infinity, no such $M$ will work.)

Comment: But then the question arises: How do I show that n/log(n) tends to infinity? :/

Comment: @CubbyKushi If you know l'Hopital's rule, then this is straightforward. Alternatively Hagen von Eitzen gives a simple argument contingent on you knowing that $e^t \ge 1+t$ for all $t$.